# No method named `post` found for type `hyper::Client` in Hyper 0.11

Tags: rust, hyper

I want use to Hyper for crafting HTTP requests. Calling `Client::get` works fine but other methods such as `Client::post` and `Client::head` cause an compilation error.

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate tokio_core;

use std::io::{self, Write};
use futures::{Future, Stream};
use hyper::Client;
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;

fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let client = Client::new(&core.handle());

    let uri = "http://httpbin.org/ip".parse().unwrap();
    let work = client.post(uri).and_then(|res| {
        // if post changed to get it will work correctly
        println!("Response: {}", res.status());

        res.body("x=z")
            .for_each(|chunk| io::stdout().write_all(&chunk).map_err(From::from))
    });
    core.run(work).unwrap();
}
```

error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `post` found for type `hyper::Client<hyper::client::HttpConnector>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:15:23
   |
15 |     let work = client.post(uri).and_then(|res| {
   |                       ^^^^

error[E0277]: the trait bound `[u8]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:20:24
   |
20 |             .for_each(|chunk| io::stdout().write_all(&chunk).map_err(From::from))
   |                        ^^^^^ `[u8]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[u8]`
   = note: all local variables must have a statically known size
```

Comment: `hyper::Client` does not have a post method! See: https://docs.rs/hyper/0.11.16/hyper/client/struct.Client.html#impl-2. It only has `get()` and `request()`. `client.request(Request::new(Method::Post, uri))` is appropriate.

Comment: @daboross Looks like this is an answer. You should post it as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Boiethios I would, but it's largely redundant with Shepmaster's answer now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no secret trickery to the error message. You are getting the error "no method named `post` found for type `hyper::Client`" *because there's no such method*.

If you review the documentation for [`Client`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.11.16/hyper/client/struct.Client.html), you can see all the methods it has. None of them are `post`.

Instead, you need to use `Client::request` and pass in a [`Request`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.11.16/hyper/struct.Request.html) value. The constructor for `Request` accepts a [`Method`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.11.16/hyper/enum.Method.html) which denotes the HTTP method to use.

```
use hyper::{Client, Request, Method};

fn main() {
    // ...

    let uri = "http://httpbin.org/ip".parse().unwrap();
    let req = Request::new(Method::Post, uri);

    let work = client.request(req).and_then(|res| {
        // ...
    });
}
```

The [crate documentation](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.11.16/hyper/index.html) says:

> If just starting out, **check out the [Guides](https://hyper.rs/guides/) first**.

There is a guide for exactly your case: [Advanced Client Usage](https://hyper.rs/guides/client/advanced/).

Comment: I have been unable implement POST using that Advanced Client Usage guide.  Out of nowhere it states: "Remember, the work in post won’t actually do anything until we give the future to the core."

Comment: @SteveB make sure you read preceding guides as well; presumably and *advanced* guide builds on simpler guides that come before it. Also note that this Q&A is about Hyper 0.11 while the current version of Hyper is 0.12, which is greatly changed to accommodate futures.